# Calculate $\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^{n+1} - x^{k+1} + x^k - nx + n - 1}{(x-1)^2} , n,k \in \Bbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Calculate $$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^{n+1} - x^{k+1} + x^k - nx + n - 1}{(x-1)^2} , n,k \in \Bbb{N}$$

I tried to group numerator so:
$$ (x^{n+1} - 1) - (x^{k+1} - x^k) - (nx - n) = (x - 1)(... - x^k - n) $$

Then I reduce fraction with $(x - 1)$.
But what to do next?

Comment: Forgot to say that L'Hopital and derivatives are forbidden for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=1+t$. Noting
$$ (1+t)^n=1+\binom{n}{1}t+\binom{n}{2}t^2+O(t^3)$$
so
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^{n+1} - x^{k+1} + x^k - nx + n - 1}{(x-1)^2} \\
&=&\lim_{t \to 0 }\frac{(1+t)^{n+1} - (1+t)^{k+1} + (1+t)^k - n(1+t) + n - 1}{t^2} \\
&=&\lim_{t \to 0}\frac1{t^2}\left\{\left[1+\binom{n}{1}t+\binom{n}{2}t^2+O(t^3)\right] \right.\\
&&- \left[1+\binom{k+1}{1}t+\binom{k+1}{2}t^2+O(t^3)\right] \\
&&\left.+ \left[1+\binom{k}{1}t+\binom{k}{2}t^2+O(t^3)\right]^k - n(1+t) + n - 1\right\}\\
&=&\lim_{t \to 0}\frac1{t^2}\left\{\left[\binom{n}{2}-\binom{k+1}{2}+\binom{k}{2}\right]t^2+O(t^3)\right\}\\
&=&\binom{n}{2}-\binom{k+1}{2}+\binom{k}{2}\\
&=&\frac{n^2-n-2k}{2}.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 2):

Consider the polynomial on the numerator 
$p(x) = x^{n+1} - x^{k+1} + x^k - nx + n - 1.$ Then $p(1) = 0.$ Moreover, $p'(x) = (n+1) x^n -(k+1)x^k + kx^{k-1} - n $ which implies that $p'(1) = (n+1) - (k+1) + k -n = 0.$ This shows that $x=1$ is a double root of the polynomial $p(x),$ and so it factors as $p(x) = (x-1)^2 q(x)$ for some polynomial $q$ of degree $n-2.$ (I'll leave it as an interesting exercise for you to find this polynomial $q.$) Then
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{p(x)}{(x-1)^2 } = \lim_{x \to 1} q(x) = q(1),
$$
since $q$ is a polynomial, hence continuous.